# Why would my loop start at 1 rather than 0?

Tags: java

I am doing some exercises on codingbat because I have been struggling with arrays. The question was:

"Return the "centered" average of an array of ints, which we'll say is the mean average of the values, except ignoring the largest and smallest values in the array. If there are multiple copies of the smallest value, ignore just one copy, and likewise for the largest value. Use int division to produce the final average. You may assume that the array is length 3 or more."

I was able to code the solution correctly except for 1 part.

The correct code is:

```
public int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
  int max = nums[0];
  int min = nums[0]; 
  int add = nums[0];

  for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
   add += nums[i];  
   if(nums[i] > max){
   max = nums[i];
  }
   else if(nums[i] < min){
   min = nums[i];
  }
 }
   return (add - max - min) / (nums.length - 2);
}
```

My question is why are we starting at int i = 1 rather than 0? If you start at 1 aren't you skipping over a cell?

Comment: Well, you are setting `max`, `min` and `add` for i=0, so no need to do it again in the loop.

Comment: Because `int add = nums[0];` already accounts for that (initial) value, hence your loops starts right after `nums[0]`...you don't have to (nor can) loop over it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization:

```
int max = nums[0];
int min = nums[0]; 
int add = nums[0];
```

handles the case when i = 0 for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting max, min and add from zero index of array.By doing this u are finding min and max from a single loop iteration(i.e.. by compairing this values from the other elements of array). If u havn't done this then u have to use some other logic to find min and max of array like O(n)^2 soln.